# Wildcard route: error content showing on homepage

Tags: angular, routes

So I'm learning wildcard route in angular 7 and when I made the error page, the content of said error page shows up in the homepage too. For added reference, im exporting the components in an array called `routingComponents`. I don't know why that is happening considering I even kept the path for the error page in the end too.Should I make changes to my HTML file? Here is my `app-routing.module.ts` code

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path:'departments',component: DepartmentListComponent},
 {path: 'employees', component: EmployeeListComponent},
 {path: "**", component:PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponenets = [DepartmentListComponent, 
 EmployeeListComponent,
 PageNotFoundComponent]
```

Comment: Do you have a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue?

Comment: My files arent uploading on Stackblitz, if it makes it any easier, I did upload the src on [Github](https://github.com/moon18/Error-Handling) if that helps